# Can I "mount" an AMI volume (ebs) in serverless (aws-lambda)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Can I "mount" an AMI (or ebs volume) in serverless (aws-lambda)?
My goal is to run some quick scan on AMIs content using Lambda, without using an EC2 instance for that.

Comment: No you cannot. That is not a supported feature of AWS Lambda. Also, there is no such thing as AMI volumes. AMIs are composed of EBS snapshots. An EBS volume may be created from an AMI, but at that point it is not part of an AMI anymore.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Converting it won’t be a problem. But still, as you said, sadly doesn’t seem to be supported. I have also updated the question with your feedback.

Comment: You could try this approach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-accessing-snapshot.html

Comment: Looks promising, thanks!